# Grails 3 with SAML - authentication failure

Tags: grails, saml, spring-saml

I have created a Grails (v3.3.6) web app using the 
[Grails Spring Security SAML Plugin (v3.3.0)](https://jeffwils.github.io/grails-spring-security-saml/).
Unfortunately, I am having trouble getting it
configured correctly. This is for a project called 'coworkers', so you
will see that name referenced in various places (below). We are using
PingFederate for our SAML authentication.

Problem: The authentication seems to working on the PingFederate side, but
then the browser is being sent into an *infinite loop*, going back and forth between my app and PingFederate (**UPDATE:** the infinite loop has 
been fixed, but the source of the problem remains). Logs indicate a `MetadataProviderException` (see the end of the stacktrace below).

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is part of my `application.yml` config file:

```
---
grails:
    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            saml:
                active: true  # false does not work as of saml plugin v3.3.0
                afterLoginUrl: '/'
                afterLogoutUrl: '/'
                responseSkew: 300
                signatureAlgorithm: 'rsa-sha256'
                digestAlgorithm: 'sha256'
                userGroupAttribute: 'roles'
                autoCreate:
                    active: false  # If you want the plugin to generate users in the DB as they are authenticated via SAML
                    key: 'id'
                    assignAuthorities: false  # If you want the plugin to assign the authorities that come from the SAML message
                metadata:
                    defaultIdp: 'fed.saml2'  # 'coworkers' # @see https://github.com/jeffwils/grails-spring-security-saml/issues/34#issuecomment-396524285
                    url: '/saml/metadata'
                    providers:
                        ping: 'security/idp.xml'
                    sp:
                        file: 'security/sp.xml'
                        defaults:
                            local: false
                            entityId: 'coworkers'
                            alias: 'coworkers'
                            securityProfile: 'metaiop'  # 'pkix' or 'metaiop'
                            signingKey: 'coworkers'
                            encryptionKey: 'coworkers'
                            tlsKey: 'coworkers'
                            requireArtifactResolveSigned: false
                            requireLogoutRequestSigned: false
                            requireLogoutResponseSigned: false
                keyManager:
                    storeFile: 'classpath:security/mykeystore.jks'
                    storePass: 'mypassword'
                    passwords:
                        coworkers: 'mypassword'
                    defaultKey: ''
```

Here is my `sp.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <md:EntityDescriptor entityID="coworkers" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:Extensions>
      <idpdisco:DiscoveryResponse xmlns:idpdisco="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol" Location="http://myserver/login/auth/alias/coworkers?disco=false"/>
    </md:Extensions>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>CERTIFICATEREMOVED</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://myserver/saml/SingleLogout/alias/coworkers"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://myserver/saml/SingleLogout/alias/coworkers"/>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://myserver/saml/SingleLogout/alias/coworkers"/>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://myserver/saml/SSO/alias/coworkers" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="http://myserver/saml/SSO/alias/coworkers" index="1" isDefault="false"/>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:PAOS" Location="http://myserver/saml/SSO/alias/coworkers" index="2" isDefault="false"/>
  </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Here is my `idp.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="byhfqDHEyvF6TnZ1-nhQEyP0.kQ" cacheDuration="PT1440M" entityID="fed.saml2">
  <md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>CERTIFICATEREMOVED</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://fed/idp/SSO.saml2"/>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://fed/idp/SSO.saml2"/>
  </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Here is the stacktrace from the logs:

```
2018-07-13 14:29:00.184 [] DEBUG --- [p-nio-80-exec-3] o.s.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter   : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error determining metadata contracts

org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error determining metadata contracts
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter.doFilter(MetadataDisplayFilter.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No local entity found for alias coworkers, verify your configuration.
        at org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl.populateLocalEntityId(SAMLContextProviderImpl.java:279)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl.getLocalEntity(SAMLContextProviderImpl.java:106)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:79)
        ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see that in application.yml you have mentioned "entityId" as "https://coworkers/", but in your SP metadata file the entityId is "http://myserver/coworkers". Make both of them same and try again.

Comment: Thank for you pointing that out to me. It must have been an edit mistake on my part. I have checked my actual files and they are correct.

Comment: "No local entity found for alias coworkers" in link you mentioned, in the sample configuration, the entityId and alias is same. Did you try that??

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just tried making the entityId="coworkers" in the sp.xml file. Unfortunately, it has had no effect.

Comment: Since authentication was failing, at least according to the SAML plugin, it was logging this message: `Delegating to authentication failure handler...`, which is hard-coded in the plugin as `/log4J/logging`, which does not exist. So I created a "log4J" controller with a "logging" action just to see what would happen. Now the infinite loop has stopped, but the browser just stops on the `/log4J/logging` URL and nothing further happens. The same exception is still being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of experimenting, I finally just tried setting the `saml.metadata.sp.defaults.local` to `true`. This seems to have fixed my problem! I obviously misunderstood the description of this setting. @Agam, I really appreciated your assistance.

Comment: OOPS!! We missed that :( Now everything makes sense. Glad you solved that. ;)